# Converting dimension feature into image using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, convert, rasterization

I have a task to convert dimension feature into image with ArcObjects.

I need to get real image that I see in ArcMap (with right size and spatial reference, of course) instead of turning feature into raster by values of some field.

Is it possible to perform feature-to-image conversion with ArcObjects?

I need solution applicable to just dimension feature class, not to layer on the map.

It seems that the [IDimensionGraphic](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDimensionGraphic.htm) interface should be used. But I don't understand what arguments should be passed to its [Draw](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDimensionGraphic_Draw.htm) method.

Answer (score 1):

Not so long ago I have done something like this with `ExportTIFF`. You can load the feature to map, zoom to it and then do sth. like this:

```
ExportTIFF docExport = new ExportTIFFClass();
(docExport as IExport).Resolution = (short)iOutputResolution;

(docExport as IExport).PixelBounds = PixelBoundsEnv;
(docExport as IExport).ExportFileName = sOutputDir + ...

(docExport as IExportTIFF).GeoTiff = true;
(docExport as IWorldFileSettings).MapExtent = docMapExtEnv;
(docExport as IWorldFileSettings).OutputWorldFile = true;

if (docExport is IExportImage)
{
    (docExport as IExportImage).ImageType = esriExportImageType.esriExportImageTypeIndexed;
   if (docActiveView.ScreenDisplay is IScreenDisplay2)
   {
        IColor col = new RgbColorClass();
        col.RGB=(docActiveView.ScreenDisplay as IScreenDisplay2).BackgroundRGB;
        (docExport as IExportImage).BackgroundColor = col;
   }
}
long hdc = (docExport as IExport).StartExporting();

IEnvelope dummy = null;
docActiveView.Output((int)hdc, (System.Int16)((docExport as IExport).Resolution), ref exportRECT, docMapExtEnv, null);

(docExport as IExport).FinishExporting();
(docExport as IExport).Cleanup();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this code won't work without document (and thereby without map), for example, in geoprocessing function in background mode. I need solution applicable to just dimension feature class, not to layer on the map. I've updated my question to reflect this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

IDimensionGraphic.Draw requires an ITransformation and hDC, a device context.

The device context can be obtained using the win32 method [GetDC](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getdc), or as it says for [IDisplay.StartDrawing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000v9000000),

> call IDisplay::StartDrawing with a value of 0 for the hDC as this will automatically use the Windows API function GetDC to populate IScreenDisplay::WindowDC with the hDC of the main display

This might also work for IDimensionGraphic::Draw. It's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide code of method to save dimension feature into image? Something like DimensionToImage(IDimensionFeature feature, string filePath) { ... }